# Is there any webhook support or do we get any notification for new function created in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

We did check AWS Lambda create function https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started.html.

We need help to know if there is any webhook support or do we get any notification when new function created in AWS Lambda.

Kindly help me know more on this. TIA !!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html). It logs all actions performed in your AWS account. You should be able to create an SNS notification for Lambda creation, then hook up that notification to whatever you want to happen.

I'm not sure whether CloudTrail will capture creation of Lambda's from CloudFormation, but I'm assuming you don't want to alert on that anyway.